# Jmeter execution on ec2 via AWS SSM (run command) and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jmeter, aws-ssm

I was able to successfully setup and run tests on `ec2` instance by setting up `JMeter`, `Grafana` (UI to display results) and a database called `influxDB`. The only issue is that a user has to logon to the instance to run the test as the test plans need to be uploaded on the instance for the same.

I was hoping if I could leverage SSM (`aws` run command) by which I can store the test plan in an `S3` bucket and then use SSM to take this test plan and run the test from AWS SSM directly instead of logging onto the `ec2` instance?

Please note, I would like to still run the test on the ec2 instance but as a user I don't want to login to the instance directly but rather have aws ssm take care of this.

Any insight on the same will be helpful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mount an S3 bucket and fix the problem.